# javascript/python/flask - formData not sending uploaded file to server

Tags: javascript, python, flask, multipartform-data

I'm trying to send a user uploaded file to my server through an `axios` POST request with `formData` and it is not working.

What doesn't work:

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('batch', batch);
formData.append('file', files[i]);

console.log(formData.get('batch')); // outputs 894489 correctly
console.log(formData.get('file')); // outputs fileObject correctly

axios.post('/api/upload', formData, {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
    });
```

response from python

```
print(request.form)
# ImmutableMultiDict([('batch', '894489')])
# Why is the file missing?
```

What does work:

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('batch', batch);
formData.append('file', 'test');

console.log(formData.get('batch')); // outputs 894489 correctly
console.log(formData.get('file')); // outputs 'test' correctly

axios.post('/api/upload', formData, {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
    });
```

response from python

```
print(request.form)
# ImmutableMultiDict([('batch', '894489'), ('file', 'test')])
# Why is the file appearing?
```

My `files[i]` is a valid file and is being recognized in JS. This is confirmed with the `console.log(formData.get('file'));` which always outputs the correct file.

Somewhere along the way the file is lost and unavailable to python yet strangely if I append a string instead, it works. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From inside Flask, the files should be accessible using this:

```
request.files['file']
```

Comment: Thanks man. How did I not see it...

Comment: Not your fault. I have to say sometimes I also get caught in some things when trying to make my front-end talk to flask. I always have to google it